# I Want to send file from android to raspberry Pi via bluetooth programatically(Automatically)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, data-collection

I had a csv file on android device and that csv file is updated in every 10 sec, I want to send that file from that device to raspberry Pi via bluetooth. Raspberry Pi received file manually from that device but I want that automatically after 10sec Pi is collecting that csv file from device and stord on Pi. How can I achieve this? If someone can help me out then it is very helpful to me.

Comment: How big is your file ? Because BLE has a very low data rate compared to BR/EDR. In BLE it depends of a lot of factors but typically the useful data rate (not counting protocol overhead) is in the range of a few kB/s. Depending of your devices you will have a rate between 2 and 15kB/s.

Comment: It is a very small file around 10-15 kB and that may be ok for BLE. but how can i transfer this automatically from device to pi?

Comment: Does it have to go via Bluetooth? Aren't the devices on the same network?

Comment: No I must send it via bluetooth only. Any Idea?